# Number of ways to fill a grid with balls

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ways to fill a $3\times 3$ grid (with corners defined as $a,b,c,d$) if you have 3 black and 6 white marbles.

Note: This question was asked in an e-litmus exam and is not an assignment question.

Comment: Hint: Look at the number of ways to arrange the $6$ white marbles and $3$ black marbles inside the grid.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/520672/28900).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

area of the grid =$9$

No. of ways of arranging 3 black marbles or 6 white marbles = $9 \choose 3$ = $84$.